# Как получить район города по координатам через API?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

**Сторонние сервисы мне НЕ интересны.**

Например, у города Уфа есть Советский район, и он находится через поиск, и его полигон выделяется.

У нас есть, например, координаты точки в этом районе: **[54.73554432816171, 55.98554909014894]**.

Вызов этих методов geocode (*res_geo.getAddressLine(), res_geo.getLocalities(), res_geo.getThoroughfare(), res_geo.getPremise(), res_geo.getAdministrativeAreas()*) даст следующие значения, соответственно:

*Россия, Республика Башкортостан, Уфа, улица 8 Марта, 32/1 ["Уфа"] улица 8 Марта undefined (2) ["Республика Башкортостан", "городской округ Уфа"]*

При этом района города нет, и методов, судя по апи, не осталось для его получения. Иногда показывает микрорайон, но это не то что мне нужно. Версия апи 2.1.

ПС, наткнулся на ссылки dimik. 
1. jsfiddle.net/rL7bztfw
2. jsfiddle.net/rL7bztfw/1

1 - без уточнения, определяет район, 2 - с уточнением, не определяет. (но там другие координаты, в 1 случае это круг, дорога, без конкретного адреса)

У себя я пробовал без уточнения, с уточнением locality - нет района. С уточнением district - показывает микрорайон.

В **.properties.get('metaDataProperty') .getAll()** тоже нет советского района

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kind=district [возвращает](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=7abf2304-201c-4a61-b831-984dd5ff2199&kind=district&geocode=55.98554909014894%2054.73554432816171) район вторым результатом.

Comment: Спасибо, но уже использую LocationIQ. Тут надо еще и под жёсткую политику подстроиться, использовать отдельное апи, хотя есть стандартное с функционалом на 99% нужное, но не возращающее 2 результат...